# Get Azure AD directory users in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure-active-directory

I have a Rails 6 application and I want to use Azure Active Directory as an authentication system (with open id connect, saml2 and ldap).
The authentication is done.
Now I am trying to display user information like names or email addresses. I also want to be able to export all users of a directory.

I have tried to set a configuration up like so:

- In my Rails app, in the admin panel, an admin can configure Azure AD for my application
- in the config, the admin copies and pastes the configuration link provided by Azure AD (a JSON response)
- Then, copies and pastes the app client_id
- Then, the tenant_id (directory id)

Here is a piece of code that I expected to work:

```
def update_oidc
    identity_provider = IdentityProvider.find_by(provider_type: 'open_id_connect', id: params[:id])
    client_id = params[:client_id].strip
    metadata_url = params[:metadata_url].strip
    tenant_id = params[:tenant_id].strip

    metadata = HTTParty.get(metadata_url).parsed_response

    identity_provider.update(config: {
      metadata: metadata,
      metadata_url: metadata_url,
      client_id: client_id,
      tenant_id: tenant_id,
    })

    if tenant_id 
      directory_access_url = "https://graph.windows.net/#{tenant_id}/users?api-version=1.6"
      result = HTTParty.get(directory_access_url).parsed_response

      identity_provider.directories.find_or_create_by(tenant_id: tenant_id).update(
        business_phones: result["business_phones"],
        display_name: result["display_name"],
        given_name: result["given_name"],
        job_title: result["job_title"],
        email: result["user_principal_name"],
        mobile_phone: result["mobile_phone"],
        office_location: result["office_location"],
        surname: result["surname"]
      )
    end

    redirect_to identity_provider
  end
```

As the `tenant_id` is the directory id, i thought that we might be able to access user info this way (and following the Microsoft Docs). The thing is, it doesn't work because even though I'm connected to my Azure AD directory in my app, when I run `result = HTTParty.get(directory_access_url).parsed_response`, i have an authentication error telling me the token has expired or that i need to be connected.

I don't want to use PowerShell or anything like this. I want to be able to access directories data through my app.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong or come up with an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just according to your code, I think you want to get the collection of users via the Azure AD Graph REST API [`Get users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#get-users--) using [`jnunemaker/httparty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) library.

However, it seems to be missing the required header `Authorization` with its value like `Bearer eyJ0eX ... FWSXfwtQ` as the section [`Authentication and authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview#authentication-and-authorization--) of the offical document [`Operations overview | Graph API concepts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview) said. Meanwhile, you have done the authentication with `OpenID Connect`, but Azure AD Graph API requires the access token as `Authorization` value from OAuth2 as the content below said.

> The Graph API performs authorization based on OAuth 2.0 permission scopes present in the token. For more information about the permission scopes that the Graph API exposes, see [Graph API Permission Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes).
>
> In order for your app to authenticate with Azure AD and call the Graph API, you must add it to your tenant and configure it to require permissions (OAuth 2.0 permission scopes) for Windows Azure Active Directory. For information about adding and configuring an app, see [Integrating Applications with Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/).
>
> Azure AD uses the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol. You can learn more about OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD, including supported flows and access tokens in [OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645545.aspx).

So I'm afraid you have to get the access token manually via OAuth2 for Azure AD again for using Graph API, or just simply refer to the sample code [`samples/authorization_code_example/web_app.rb`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby/blob/dev/samples/authorization_code_example/web_app.rb) using the `adal` library of GitHub repo [`AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby) for Ruby.

Comment: Thanks. I can now retrieve directory information in my server using adal. After searches, i still can't display those info in my view. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @jdps If you have got those info from Azure AD, I think it should be simple for displaying them to a web page in rails. May you can create a new SO thread and post what code you did currently to ask for helps.

Comment: Here is my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58307567/azure-active-directory-display-directory-information-in-views